# How to check if phonegap app using WKWebview

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, mobile-safari, wkwebview

Could not find information. I built pg app with 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine'.

How to check if phonegap web app on ios 9.2 is really using WKWebview? Could not find info how userAgent string should look like for WKWebView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Previous answer doesn't work on iOS 10, but you can use this code

```
if (window.webkit) {
    //WKWebView            
}
```

Old answer:
You can check for indexedDB

```
if (window.indexedDB) {
    //WKWebView
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, thougth though safari on iOS 8 already supports it))

Comment: safari supports it, but not the UIWebView

Comment: The CDWKWebViewEngine plugin is also only available for iOS 9

Comment: Yeah, on iOS 8 it uses the UIWebView, unless you install the wkwebview-engine-localhost too https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost. If you use telerik's wkwebview plugin it works on iOS 8 too. This code works on any case.